# Finding Repeated Eigenvalues for $\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & x & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & x \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reviewing some linear algebra. I'm having trouble with this problem:

> For what values of $x$ does the matrix 
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     3 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & x & 2 \\
>     0 & 2 & x 
> \end{bmatrix}
>   Have at least one repeated eigenvalue?

I'm not sure how to start this (aside from writing down the characteristic polynomial).

Edited: As per Shaun's direction.

Comment: What does it mean to be an eigenvalue? How do we find eigenvalues? Answering these should help for #1

Comment: 1. Write down the characteristic polynomial. 2. Swap rows and multiply rows by a number may change the eigenvalues, and seems no pattern could adopt, example: $\boldsymbol I_2$, swap rows would give $\pm 1$ instead of $1,1$, then multiply row 2 by $-2$ gives no real eigenvalues.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun Sorry, better? I split the questions

Comment: Yes. I've changed the title to be a little more specific though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{equation}
 p(\lambda) =\det 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  3 - \lambda& 0 & 0 \\
  0 & x - \lambda& 2 \\
  0 & 2 & x - \lambda
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 0
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 (3-\lambda)( (x-\lambda)^2 - 4) = (\lambda - 3)(x - \lambda - 2)(x - \lambda + 2) = 0
\end{equation}
So no matter what there is $\lambda_1 = 3$. Arguement goes on the other two eigenvalues $\lambda_2 = x - 2$ and $\lambda_3 = x + 2$. You've got the following cases:

- $\lambda_2 \neq \lambda_3$ no matter what.
- $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$ gives $ x = 3 + 2 = 5$
- $\lambda_1 = \lambda_3$ gives $x = 3-2 = 1$

So two values of $x$ which are $1,5$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the matrix $A$ is given by the following matrix

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & x & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & x \end{bmatrix}  \tag{1} $$

in order find the eigenvalues we do the following

$$ \det(A - I \lambda)  = \det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 3 - \lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & x - \lambda  & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & x - \lambda \end{bmatrix}\right)  \tag{2}$$

then we get

$$ \det(A - I \lambda)  = (3-\lambda) \cdot \begin{vmatrix} x -\lambda & 2 \\ 2 & x-\lambda  \end{vmatrix} - 0 \cdot \begin{vmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & x -\lambda  \end{vmatrix} +0 \cdot \begin{vmatrix}  0 & x- \lambda \\ 0 & 2 \end{vmatrix}   \tag{3} $$
$$  \det(A - I \lambda)  = (3-\lambda) \cdot  \left( ( x-\lambda)^{2} - 2^{2}\right) \tag{4} $$

$$  \det(A - I \lambda)  = (3-\lambda) \cdot  \left( \lambda^{2}  -2\lambda x + x^{2} -4\right) \tag{5} $$

So you get repeated eigenvalues when this expression $ \lambda^{2}  -2\lambda x + x^{2} -4 $ generates them.

We want for the expression to generate eigenvalues that are equal to $3$
Note then for the expression

$$  \lambda^{2}  -2\lambda x + x^{2} -4 \tag{6}$$

if we insert $ x=1$  we get

$$  \lambda^{2}  -2\lambda  + 1 -4 = \lambda^{2} - 2\lambda -3 \tag{7} $$

$$ \lambda^{2} -2\lambda -3 = (\lambda-3)(\lambda +1) \tag{8} $$

So we have

$$ \det(A-I\lambda) =(3-\lambda) (\lambda-3)(\lambda+1) \tag{9}$$
letting $x=5$
$$ \lambda^{2}  -2\lambda 5 + 25 -4 = \lambda^{2} -10\lambda + 21  
\tag{10}$$

$$ \lambda^{2} -10 \lambda +21 = (\lambda -7)(\lambda-3) \tag{11} $$

$$ \det(A-I\lambda) = (3-\lambda) (\lambda-7)(\lambda-3) \tag{12}$$

Comment: they say the solution is x=1 or x=5. Do you see how they obtain that?

Comment: I'm working on that part right now.

Comment: You also get a repeated eigenvalue when the quadratic is solved by $\lambda=3$.

Comment: OH! got it, thanks paul. factor $((x-\lambda)^2-4)$ to  $((x-\lambda)-2)((x-\lambda)+2)$ and set lambda equal to 3 to see the two possible values of $x$.